# How to solve "Please correct the errors on this form." on Blogger?

Tags: blogger, adsense

I'm getting following error on blogger while adding AdSense Gadget.

> Please correct the errors on this form.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related. It may be on-topic on [webmasters.se] or addressed by contacting Blogger support

Comment: Althought off-topic, the google account you are trying to add your adsense gadget is not active. That's why you get this error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

We should wait 24 hours after making the adsense accound. Because they have a process about our accound around a day or more..[image]